# In react, How do I import createRoot?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am experimenting with React.

In the following script I have imported 'createRoot'.

The browser console throws a warning:

> You are importing createRoot from "react-dom" which is not supported.
> You should instead import it from "react-dom/client".

However, in my script I have imported createRoot from 'react-dom/client'.

What is going wrong here?

This is the current state of the script:

```
import React from 'react' ;
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';



export default function TodoList() {

    return(
    <>
    <h1>Lets do stuff!</h1>
    </>
    )

}

const app = document.getElementById('app');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(app);
```

Comment: Did you try to call createRoot instead of ReactDOM.createRoot ?

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `createRoot`, not from `ReactDOM`

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';

// X
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(app);  
// V
const root = createRoot(app);
```

PS: [See React Doc](https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In React 18, you no longer import from `react-dom` directly. Instead, you import the `createRoot` function from `react-dom/client` and you create a root based on the `div` element with `id="app"` you get from the DOM. Then, you render your `<App />` component (or however you named it) by calling the `root.render` function and passing your component (which is the root of your app).

Your `index.jsx` (or `index.js` file) should look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<App />);
```

- [Related article in the React Docs](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#updates-to-client-rendering-apis)